# Elliptical corners for Group Box control in VC++ (MFC)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I would like to round the corners of Group Box control/ Static control in VC++.

Would like to do round the any no of group box controls which are present in GUI.

Comment: There are no special flags and such for round corners. You have to draw it yourself. Note that Window 8 and 10 use square edges, so round corners may look odd in those systems.

Comment: You could just install WindowBlinds.

Comment: Is it not possible with Subclassing ? or custom control ?